# How do I set up this Newton's Method problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm looking at problem #40. Before going further, this is homework, so I don't want the answer. I just want guidance, and if I'm on the wrong track, I want to be pushed in the right direction.

[Single Variable Calculus - Problem # 40](http://books.google.com/books?id=uymSkn3gD9IC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=using%20the%20value%20r%20=%203.04042%20x%2010%5E-6%20find%20the&source=bl&ots=sFcf7BmkaO&sig=G5y4cAbPPuBw-pRcnbCMUGWgy58&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e4UvUfL7A4eW2gXExYGQAw&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

So, I'm looking for *L1* and *L2*.

Here is what I'm doing for *L1*

1. Write equation
2. Get derivative of equation
3. Simplify
4. Use Newton's Method to solve

My work for *L1*

1. $$x^5 - (2+r)x^4 + (1+2r)x^3 - (1-r)x^2  + 2(1-r)x + r - 1 = 0$$
2. $$ 5x^4 - 4(2+r)x^3 + 3(1+2r)x^2 - 2(1-r)x  + 2(1-r) + r = 0 $$
3. $$ 5x^4 - 8x^3 + 4rx^3 + 3x^2 + 6rx^2 - 2x - 2rx - 2r + r +2 = 0 $$

I assume after that I fill in the r value and then use Newton's Method to finish it off?

Now for *L2*

1. Write equation
2. Get derivative of equation
3. Simplify
4. Use Newton's Method to solve

Here is what I'm doing for *L2*

1. $$ p(x) - 2rx^2 = 0 $$
2. $$ p(x)' - 4rx $$
3. $$ 5x^4 - 8x^3 + 4rx^3 + 3x^2 + 6rx^2 - 2x - 6rx - 2r + r +2 = 0 $$

Can someone check my work and tell me whether I'm on the correct track? If I am, do my derivatives look correct?

Comment: the derivatives are correct. And I remember from my previous life that while calculating L1, we have a fifth-degree equation. So, most of it is right.

Comment: For $L1$, you want to take the function to include the 2, that is, your $f(x)$ is the entire expression including the 2. Note, for $L2$, you have $p(x) - 2rx^2 = 0$, so you would repeat the process as above with the additional term. There may be an easier approach to $L2$.

Comment: @Amzoti So for *L1* I just need to keep the 2 and leave it set to 0? And for *L2* I just need to add the negative sign that I missed? At Cheeku, thanks for letting me know that I'm on the right track.

Comment: @JoseBruchez: yes, recall, you want the setup to be finding the root of $f(x) = 0$, when you setup the Newton form.

Comment: @Amzoti I went back and edited my answers. If those look correct now, I can just plug those into Newton's Method and come out with my answers :)

Comment: For L1, you are golden - the way you wrote up L2 is confusing to me because it also has p(x) in front (is that clear)?

Comment: @Amzoti Apologies! Originally I thought the negative sign was an equal sign which is why I thought the equation was simply $p(x) = 2rx^2$. So I just need to add $-4rx$ and *L1* to get *L2*, correct? (edited it above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$(1)$ you are okay for $L1$.

$(2)$ For $L2$, you want to set:

$$w(x) = p(x) - 2rx^2 = 0$$

Using $w(x)$, repeat the same process you did for $L1$.

In other words, think of $w(x)$ as a new function of $x$.

**Update**

I think you have done the correct thing, but the way you are showing it is unclear. Here is what I mean, to be clear.

For L1:

$$f(x) = x^5 - (2+r)x^4 + (1+2r)x^3 - (1-r)x^2  + 2(1-r)x + r - 1$$

$$f'(x) = 2x(−1+r)+3x^2(1+2r) +4x^2(−2−r)+5x^4 + 2(1−r)$$

For L2:

$$w(x) = x^5 - (2+r)x^4 + (1+2r)x^3 - (1-r)x^2  + 2(1-r)x + r - 1 - 2rx^2$$

$$w'(x) = 2x(−1+r)+3x^2(1+2r)+4x^3(−2−r)+5x^4+2(1−r)$$

Now, you'll setup the Newton iteration using:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

using each of L1 and L2.

**Update**

The real root for $L_1 = 0.989989$ (there are also four imaginary roots).

The  real root for $L_2 = 1.01008$ (there are also four imaginary roots).

You can compare the Newton-Rapshon results to these numbers and they should be very close.

Regards

Comment: Sorry to bother you so long after this question, but I forgot to check my answer. Do these sound correct: L1 = 0.999702267 and L2 = 1.010078

Comment: What are the starting points for those values? Also, you know the exact results for each! Can you compare your $L1$ and $L2$ to the exact roots (you'll know right away)? Regards

Comment: @JoseBruchez: Please see my update, I calculate the real root using a diffent method and look at how those match with yous! I did not use Newton, but looks to me like you did great! Regards

Comment: Great job, Amzoti: unupvoted hero until now! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: That was a nice problem to guide the students, so was fun! Thx